# Is a 105 cm steel wire a suspect item in a hand baggage?

Tags: airport-security

For my next biking holiday in Asia I need to carry with me also the necessary to attach the panniers to the bike I will be renting at my destination.

An item among these is a 105 cm long steel wire, between 1 and 2 mm thick. (see picture)

[image]

As far as I know it is not among the forbidden items, but I am not sure it would not rise alarm in some zealous staff member.

Since having it removed from my hand baggage would be a huge inconvenience for my trip, should I consider other solutions for having it at destination or can I safely take it on board with me?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but if it's not explicitly banned it is up to the security personnel and how they're feeling that day. Some are very permissive, others confiscate my wheelchair-bound grandmother's knitting needles.

Comment: Why don't you put them in checked luggage?

Comment: @Johanna If a 7cm swiss army knife is a weapon, knitting needles sure are too. They'd confiscate fists if it wouldn't give such a bloody mess.

Comment: You may want to look into sourcing the item in Asia (alibaba, banggood, etc.) in case you are unlucky at the TSA check.

Comment: @RHA knitting needles are allowed in hand baggage in UK https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/personal-items

Answer (score 3):

It's not explicitly banned. However, a security personnel can ban it under the wide rule of (any item that can cause harm or can be used as a weapon).

I think this wire will pass under the x-ray as a charger wire or something, it does not look dangerous to me.

Security personnel usually choose to confiscate/deny uncategorized items based on their knowledge. If they know what it is they will usually allow it, if not they will go safe and deny it.

If it raises a flag, your best bet is to hope that you get checked by a security officer who knows what this wire is used for.